# Calling a controller method within another in functional test behaves weirdly

Tags: playframework, functional-testing, playframework-1.x

It seems that when a public static method of a controller calls another public static method of the same controller explicitly (with a Java call), **Play!** doesn't know to just execute the code or redirect in functional tests.

If I have:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {
    @Test
    public void testProvesThatFunctionalTestsDoesntCallControllerMethods() {
        Response response = GET("/");

        assertEquals("", getContent(response));
    }

    @Test
    public void testProvesThatCallingItDirectlyWorksAsExpected() throws Exception {
        Response response = GET("/another");

        assertEquals("ok!", getContent(response));

    }

}
```

And:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
        another();
    }

    public static void another() {
        renderText("ok!");
    }
}
```

But if I run **play run** or **play start** and call "/" in my web browser then it returns "ok!", shouldn't **FunctionalTest** work exactly like running it in production or as if the real server? It pushes me to avoid functional test or have a huge manual setup and dependency of a pre-running web server, that's not cool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser, when you call "/" it returns "ok" but not on the first response. It firsts return a redirect (302) and then returns a 200 (ok).

In your functional test, it is the same, You have to do something like

```
Response response = GET("/");
assertStatus(302, response);
response = GET(response.headers.get("Location").value())
assertIsOk(response);
assertEquals("ok!", getContent(response));
```

Comment: You're right, but I wonder how good is it. In my project I have a method that calls another controller method and this method calls the first method in an indirect recursion, then it would return two times and redirect to the next one. Although it sounds like the desired behavior, Play! users should understand that clearly so we can avoid all this http work in favor of Java calls.

Comment: if you want to do direct java call instead of redirect call another common method with the "@Util" annotation or a common private method